# What's the use of different sections for "dynamictg.propertiescaching_validity" in Concurrency Thread Group?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Referring to the JMeter Plugin [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) documentation.

The [Configurable Properties Section](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Configurable-properties) has two sub-topic with the same name.
**dynamictg.propertiescaching_validity:**

The default value in the two sections is 20ms and 10ms.

Is this referring to same property or there is a typo in the property naming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think correct property names and values are:

- [`dynamic_tg.properties_caching_validity`](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/casutg/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/jmeter/threads/concurrency/ConcurrencyThreadStarter.java#L15) defaulting to `20`
- [`dynamic_tg.temporisation`](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/casutg/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/jmeter/threads/concurrency/ConcurrencyThreadGroup.java#L22) defaulting to `10`

there is also [`dynamic_tg.shift_rampup_start`](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/casutg/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/jmeter/threads/concurrency/ConcurrencyThreadStarter.java#L34) property defaulting to `0`

More information: [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter Part 4 - Stepping Thread Group and Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread)